# Jasper report exporting to text results in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

Currently I am using jasper v `3.7.4`

While exporting to any other format (`csv`,`xls`,`pdf`) from the same `dataset` - I have has no issues.

Exporting to `text` throws:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
> java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)     at
> java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)

Here is my code:

```
    byte[] bytes = null;
    JRTextExporter  exporter = new JRTextExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream txtReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, txtReport);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "mytxt.txt");
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_WIDTH, 2.0F);
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH, 100.0F);
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_HEIGHT, 4.0F);
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT, 50.0F);
    
    exporter.exportReport();
    bytes = txtReport.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\myfile.txt")
    System.out.println(bytes.length/1024+" Kbytes");
    fos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

I am also using a `virtualizer` as `jasperPrint` parameter

```
 JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(150);
 virtualizer.setReadOnly(false);
 params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);
```

But it does not help, and also the following warning is shown:

> WARNING: Parameter "REPORT_VIRTUALIZER" already registered, skipping
> this one.

Given that `csv` is also a "`text`" file and is generated without any problem, it is kind of strange that
exporting to `text` fails.

May be something is wrong with the parameters I provide for the exporter?

Thanks.

Comment: @Kayaman You are partially right (regarding the given code) - however the code above was created to replicate the issue - in the real code (which is inside servlet) - there is no FileOutput - everything is done in memory - and as I said earlier cvs is generated perfectly - but text fails.

Comment: If in the actual code the report is written to any stream (network) etc.  it's still the same case. Besides it doesn't matter if the csv is generated perfectly, you're running out of memory. I don't know why you would assume that a successful csv export would mean a successful text export. Text is not the same format as csv, all files are binary, and "text file" is just a distinction made for humans.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - there were very helpful - of course  you are right - I  should write directly to stream. Also, I wasn't expecting the text report being filled with so many space characters - that's the reason why the result is huge and gives OOME.

Comment: One question - the only reason to be writing to temporary `ByteArrayOutputStream` is to be able to set `response.setContentLength(bytes.length);` on servlet's response but if I write directly to the stream I have no knowledge of content length ... is there a way to obtain that information ?

Comment: You don't need or want the content length. You're interested in the report, not its size.

Comment: @Kayaman This is part of a servlet that generates reports - cvs, xls, pdf , txt etc - so when sending the result as an attachment I would like to include the contents length so that the client could estimate download time ...

Comment: Well, then you've got a choice to make. I'd go for the low-memory option, since it's 2020 and I did enough time estimating in the 90's. But if you want to provide your users with that option, then you can increase memory.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok thanks  a lot  - I am going to accept your solution (already up-voted it) and going to rephrase the question - to find out how to get rid of extra-extra white spaces in my text export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `text` and `csv` may both be *text based* formats, they're not the *same* format and therefore do not take the same amount of space.

Generating *anything* (usually reports) to memory is hazardous since while it may work in testing, a large report in production causing an OOME will wreak havoc.

Use a real stream when generating things. A `FileOutputStream`, network stream, any proper stream that doesn't store things in memory. If you're using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for "real work", you're most likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately output the report to the file, instead of first collecting it.

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\myfile.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)) {
    JRTextExporter  exporter = new JRTextExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, bos);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "mytxt.txt");
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_WIDTH, 2.0F);
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH, 100.0F);
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_HEIGHT, 4.0F);
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT, 50.0F);

    exporter.exportReport();
}
```